# Como eu faço para colocar um controle ao lado do outro com bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho esse html com bootstrap. Preciso colocar uns textbox um ao lado do outro. Usei um controle horizontal e não funcionou. No controle Produtor eu coloquei dois textbox e não funcionou.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Produtor</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-white">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-white">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">CNPJ</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-white">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo Produtor</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-white">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Filial</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-white">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Data de Inclusão</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" name="timepicker" class="b-datepicker form-control form-white" placeholder="Informe a data" data-orientation="top">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: você tem duas divs após a label produtor, coloque "col-sm-3" e teste, se quiser você pode usar o site [ http://www.bootply.com/ ] que é ótimo para isso.

Comment: Visita esta página ela te ajudará a perceber melhor essas situações. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colunar os dados conforme você fez, veja o exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ivanteles/fhoznrzt/

Comment: @IvanTeles, prefira colocar o código e o link, invés de colocar só o link.

Comment: Entendi, sempre dentro do mesmo grupo. Mudou de grupo, ela vai para a linha de baixo.

Comment: Podes explicar na resposta o que esse jsFiddle tem e que ajuda ao perguntado? Assim a resposta ficaria ainda melhor :)